# How to take screenshot in Xcode simulator without menu bar?

Tags: xcode

I would like to take a screenshot with the frame and the shadow, but when I try it with Cmd+Shift+4 the menu bar (red rectangle) is in the screenshot as well. Is there any way to create a screenshot without this? I would like to avoid to cut it out manually because the shadow looks weird after that.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking to take a screenshot of the IOS simulator as well(except the bar in red)? If so use Cmd+Shift+5.

Comment: But then the shadow is cut off.

Comment: but you can resize it can't you?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how this helps me

Comment: Couldn't you resize it to keep the shadow but not. the menu bar at the top?

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. If I try your approach the shadow is still cut off at a specific position. It doesn't look so smooth anymore

Comment: Hmm okay, sorry I must have misunderstood.